# expressjs: Dynamically load a partial into a template via route

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

Is it possible to load a specific partial and dump it into a template based on a route ?

Say I have the following:

**Routes:**

```
// contact us
app.get(‘/contact-us’, function(req, res){
  res.render(‘contact-us’);
});

// contact Ben
app.get(‘/contact-us/ben’, function(req, res){
  // get the partial with Ben’s details and put it in res.render(‘contact-us’);
});

// contact Tom
app.get(‘/contact-us/tom’, function(req, res){
  // get the partial with Tom’s details and put it in res.render(‘contact-us’);
});
```

**Templates:**

```
[views]
    |
    [contact-us]
          |- index.jade
          |- ben.jade
          |- tom.jade
```

Comment: I don't know express provide this facility, but your problem looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817213/pass-a-variable-to-view-in-every-request-node-js-express/24817305#24817305. have a look on this

Comment: Are your views actually pure javascript files, or did you mean to put `.jade`?

Comment: @scarIzYep sorry about that. They are `.jade` files